# What is statistically significant latency variation?

Tags: networking, statistics, latency

Consider the case where I have four identical routers, A, B, C, and D, running busybox and ptpd. A and B are connected by cable 1; C and D are connected by cable 2. I have a small C program on routers A and C that sends a very small packet over UDP to the opposite router, and I use pcap to detect the times that the packet was sent, and the times it arrived at the other end, and calculate the average and deviation for a thousand of these tests.

How do I tell if these cables are different?
Obviously if one is 500μs and the other is 10ms, they're different. But what if the results for one have average 200μs with standard deviation 8, and the results for the other have average 210μs and standard deviation 10. How probable is it that they are different? What calculations should I do to test this? And, on a more technical note, what is the expected variability in latency?

I understand any intermediate switches, hubs, routers etc will add to the latency and the variability of it, but if they are directly connected by a single cable, what is a normal variance?

Edit: Just to clarify a point - this isn't just a statistics question. I can use a t-test to determine probability of difference (thanks), but I'd also like to know how much variance can normally be attributed to different qualities in the network equipment. For example, if the average of the two means are 208.4 and 208.5, I would suspect that whatever the t-test might say, the cables are the same and the difference comes from the test machines. Or am I wrong? Do cables often vary by small amounts? I don't know - What's a normal variance between latencies? What test do I need to distinguish between a difference in the cables, and the equipment? (I can't switch the cables)

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on http://serverfault.com perhaps, or a maths/statistics site ?

Comment: ... like http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I delete it and repost it there?

Comment: The approach we've been using over there is to copy the post over, and then link to the StackOverflow version of the question so that people can see what's been done already.

Comment: Ok, so where should it go? I'm not sure either of those are the best place for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a two-sample t-test. You don't need to make any of the assumptions about typical variance that you are worried about, they are built into the test. Please find the appropriate Wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Two-sample_T.C2.A02_test). Statistically different, however, isn't necessarily the same as economically different. You can confirm that the latency times between the two routers are indeed different, but different by enough to matter? Hard to say without knowing more what about your situation, but be wary of getting too far in the statistical weeds.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need a primer on statistical hypothesis testing.

Then, there are several ways to answer your question, but the most classical one is to consider that the observed latency is a real variable (let's call those T, for time) which has a non-random component explained by the behaviour of each cable (let's call those C, for cable) and a random component which you cannot explain, which may come from random fluctuations or other things you forgot to take into account (let's call those E, for error).

Then, you will make a series of observations, for cable A-B, and your model is:

> T1_i = C1 + E1_i

Where you believe the contribution of the cable remains fixed and only the random variable E1 is changing.

You will also make a series of observations for cable C-D, and your model is:

> T2_i = C2 + E2_i

Where you believe the contribution of the cable remains fixed and only the random variable E2 is changing.

Now, you are pretty much solved. You'll ensure all systematic influences are eliminated, so E1 and E2 are really fluctuations. Under those conditions, you can assume they are normal (Gaussian).

Using this model you can use the independent two-sample t-test to check if C1 and C2 are different to any confidence you set beforehand.

Comment: What about if there is a consistent (non-fluctuating) difference unrelated to the cables?

Comment: Then all bets are off. Everything not explained by the model are considered 'residues'. You have to incorporate in the model all systematic sources of variation, even those that you wished to ignore (those are called 'nuisance factors'), otherwise they'll lessen your significance. (However, if their effect is small, sometimes you'll prefere a simpler model with slight less significance than an ultra-complex model that takes into account everything).

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think statistics will contribute a great deal to what you're doing here.  Your cost of collecting a datum is essentially zero, and you can collect arbitrarily huge volumes of it.  Fire off a few million/billion packets through each cable and then plot the latencies on two histograms with the same scale.  If you can't see a difference, there probably isn't a meaningful one.

Summary statistics destroy information.  There are a lot of reasons why one might want to use them anyway, but I don't think they'll be all that useful here.  If you *want* to learn the stats, I certainly applaud that - I think statistical literacy is a fundamental skill for people who want to be able to tell when somebody is feeding them a line of bullshit.  But if you just want to understand the differences in latencies between these two cables, a well-done pair of histograms will be vastly more informative.

Comment: Downvoter, would you care to actually comment on why this answer is wrong?

Comment: -1 also - you've "answered" my question by ignoring it; not helpful. Plus, your answer is wrong - histograms, as a pictorial representation, necessarily carry less information than numbers.

Comment: I hardly ignored your question; I was just trying to get at the underlying issue, which is the question of whether or not there's a meaningful difference between the two cables.  You may or may not need statistics to address that question, and the statistic you need to address it might not be the t-test (e.g., the standard t-test requires equal variances; do your distributions have that?), but there's no way to tell until you've actually looked at the data.

Comment: Also, please note that I wrote that **summary statistics** destroy information.  They must, otherwise what would be their purpose?  The mean and variance preserve less information than histograms, which bin the data instead of compacting it into two numbers.

Comment: I don't use the standard t-test, I use the Welch-Satterthwaite version that allows for unequal variances. I need an answer to the question I asked, not the "underlying issue"; If I needed an answer to a different question, I would have asked a different question.